# slider individual spring

Tags: jquery

my page have a slider like this homepage studio8169.com/?page_id=11

how i spring for example from box 2 to 5? i want make links under the box for the users. 
That the users can spring between the different boxs.

this is my slider

```
<div id="mid"> (Position: absolute, width:100%, height:400px; overflow:hidden;)

<div id="gallery"> (position:relative;width:960px;margin:0 auto;)
   <div id="slider"> (position absolute;left:0px;width:100000px;height:400px;)
      <div class="box"></div> (position:relative; float:left;)     width:960px;height:400px;
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
   <div class="btn btn_left"></div> (position:absolute;top:150px;left:0px;)
   <div class="btn btn_right"></div> (position:absolute;top:150px;right:0px;)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been doing JavaScript and jQuery for any long so you'll have to bear with me. I've had a little play and here is my first stab at it: http://jsfiddle.net/TyCsK/7/. Basically the three divs (representing your pictures) are fixed on another div that is slide within a container.

There are a couple of kinks to iron out (disable left and right buttons when you get to the end etc.) but it might be a decent starting point. Enjoy.